# Python: get data into dataframe by clicking on plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with:

- **time**: unix time with freq = 4Hz
- **signal**: a signal here simulated with n number of square waves (real signal more noisy/complex)
- **derr_1**: signal derivative used to better classify signal types.

## Objective

An expert needs to look at this signal track, and record the start/end of each sqare wave signal.

My objective is that by clicking on the plot a dataframe/dictionary is updated with start and stop times of the signals. This needs to work fast enough with my total number of points (800 thousand)

## Example code

here is the code for generating an example signal.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import plotly.express as px


# setup the signal. 

def make_time_array (start_time: float, end_time: float, freq: int=4): 
    time_array = np.arange(start_time, end_time, 1/freq)
    return time_array

def make_signal (time_array: np.array, n: int = 5, interval: int = 400, window_size=100 ): 

    # calculate the number of intervals in the time array
    num_intervals = int(np.floor((time_array.max() - time_array.min()) / interval))
    print (num_intervals)

    # select `n` random intervals from the time array
    random_intervals = np.random.choice(num_intervals, n, replace=False)

    # calculate the timestamps for the selected intervals
    selected_points = time_array.min() + (random_intervals * interval)

    # round the timestamps to match the frequency of the time array
    selected_points = np.round(selected_points, decimals=3)

    # generate the signal
    n_points = len(time_array)
    signal = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, n_points)

    # set the signal to be equal to `signal + 2` for `+-window_size` seconds around the selected points
    for idx, point in enumerate(selected_points):
        start_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(time_array - (point - window_size)))
        end_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(time_array - (point + window_size)))
        signal[start_idx:end_idx+1] += 2
    return signal




 # main 
start_time = 1625619679.0 #unix start time
total_time = 5000.25 # actual time (but then runs slow) = 202120.25
end_time = start_time +  total_time
freq = 4

number_of_square_waves = 5
distance_between_square_waves = 200
size_of_square_wave = 40 

time_array = make_time_array(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, freq=freq)
print (f"lenght time array {len(time_array)}, actual lenght = 202120*4 = 800000")
signal = make_signal(time_array=time_array, n=number_of_square_waves, interval=distance_between_square_waves, window_size=size_of_square_wave )

 # make the dataframe. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": time_array, "signal": signal})
df['derr_1'] = df['signal'].diff() * freq


 # plot the data 
df_plot = df.melt(id_vars='time')
fig = px.line(df_plot, x='time', y='value', facet_row='variable')
fig.update_layout(title = "signal example: an expert has to visually inspect and select Start time/ End time for all the 'signals' present. ")
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda yaxis: yaxis.update(showticklabels=True))
fig.show()
```

[image]

## expected output

a dataframeme with columns:

- start: when signal starts (in this case 5 entries)
- stop: when signal stops   (in this case 5 entries)

In this case the start and stop timestamps woudl be exactly that of the derivative (but in real data it isn't so simple). The start/Stop data should correspond to where the expert clicks on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple but working idea. Use the extreme values of the derivative to identify start and stop signals, then assume they come in alternative order and join them to form the expected table:

```
max_derr = df['derr_1'].max()
min_derr = df['derr_1'].min()
start_signals = df[df['derr_1']>max_derr/2]
end_signals = df[df['derr_1']<min_derr/2]
start_times = start_signals['time'].values
end_times = end_signals['time'].values
df_signals = pd.DataFrame({'start_timestamp': start_times, 'stop_timestamp': end_times})
df_signals
```